# How do I get rid of "Trusted Drive Manager"?

Tags: windows-7, windows, uninstall

I have a Dell laptop that's been experiencing some weirdness lately. Apparently Dell puts "Trusted Drive Manager" on their hardware.. Well, now I keep getting these errors:

[image]

I tried uninstalling Dell Data Protection, but it says some other package is required for the installation, which I can't install because I'll get another generic error (Dell Data Protection Access Drivers). This error pops up when I first boot, when I open a save file dialog, when I try to do a disk cleanup. How the hell do I get rid of this!?

Answer (score 2):

The tool to use to "force" .msi's to be uninstalled is [msizap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370523%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but use extreme caution with this tool and only as a last resort.

Look in Start -> Control Panel -> Programs and Features and see if "Dell Data Protection Access Drivers" is something you can uninstall.  You may need to uninstall this first before uninstalling Trusted Drive Manager - and also you may have better luck trying to uninstall all the Dell stuff there if you don't use it.

Answer (score 1):

You must uninitalize the drive before uninstalling.  Removing the software will not unlock the drive.  IF you have already uninstalled it and it wasn't uninitalied, go to the drivers page from dell, for that model laptop and reinstall.  It will have retained the passwords for all user.